# Auto-submit after switch value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to auto-submit after switch value the codes look like this.

**Index.php**

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" id="ipt" value="" name="foo">
</form>

<button type="submit" id="btn" value="Leviathan">Leviathan</button>

    <script>

    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){

    document.getElementById('ipt').value = event.target.value;
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, false);

    </script>
```

**foo.php**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['foo'])){echo $_POST['foo'];} ?>
```

the code i want is switch value from button to input then submit. with above code it switch the value but it doesn't submit anything to foo.php.

how to do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say but you should definitely put that submit button inside the form otherwise submitting with the keyboard won't work

Comment: the code on above when button element is click it will switch the value to input element value then submit it. but it doesn't pass any value to foo.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue i found in this code

Replace

> document getElementById('form1').submit();

with

> document.getElementById('form1').submit();

"." is missing in your code

Comment: Ok i tried its working fine now, when i click on "Leviathan" button it is posting the "Leviathan" value to next page foo.php , this was what you wanted? right or something else?

Comment: i have checked my index.php. it has double form that use id="form1" that's way it not pass a value. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try the below code i will submit the form when button is clicked and pass value to `foo.php`

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <form action="foo.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" id="ipt" value="asdasd" name="foo">
    </form>

    <button type="submit" id="btn" value="Leviathan" onclick="submit_form();">Leviathan</button>

        <script>

        function submit_form()
        {

             $("#form1").submit();
        }
 </script>
```

it will pass the value of `Leviathan` to `foo.php`

Comment: it will pass the value of Leviathan(hidden field) to foo.php

Comment: i have checked my index.php. it has double form that use id="form1" that's way it not pass a value. thank you.

Comment: i have tested the code it is working fine for me. passing value of id="ipt"

Comment: yeah, but using JQuery for small project. it will cost bandwith. thank you hehe

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="test-form" action="foo.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" id="ipt" name="ipt" value="" />
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Leviathan">Leviathan</button>
</form>


<script>
    var form = document.querySelector('.test-form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
        var buttonValue = form.querySelector('.submit-btn').value;
        form.querySelector('#ipt').value = buttonValue;
    });
</script>
```

"When the form is submitted set the value of the submit button on to the value of the #ipt input."

Also your php script should do `$_POST['ipt']`.

Comment: Two `name` attr on same `input tag`??

Comment: it doesn't pass a value to foo.php.

Comment: i have checked my index.php. it has double form that use id="form1" that's way it not pass a value. thank you.

Comment: @jarwo try now (it had two name attributes)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `jQuery`... I suggest to use it, It will be more simple.

#### Index.php

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" id="ipt" value="" name="foo">
</form>

<input type="button" id="btn_01" class="btn_value" value="Leviathan 01" />
<input type="button" id="btn_02" class="btn_value" value="Leviathan 02" />
<input type="button" id="btn_03" class="btn_value" value="Leviathan 03" />

<script>
    $('.btn_value').on('click', function() {
        $('#ipt').val( $(this).val() );
        $('#form1').submit();
    });
</script>
```

#### foo.php

```
<?PHP
    if ( $_POST ) {
        var_dump($_POST);
    } else {
        echo 'nothing...';
    }
?>
```

Comment: i have checked my index.php. it has double form that use id="form1" that's way it not pass a value. thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you solved. (ps: there's no need to tell each of us the same thing, you can edit your question and add the new info. Thanks anyway for the bother)